# Data is not store on Cloud Firestore using Android

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I wanna know why my data is not getting stored in Firebase Database when testing the App on Expo Go on my Android Device.
The [data is still being stored normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNYqV.png) when testing on the Web Browser

**Here is the code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text  } from 'react-native'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import "firebase/firestore";

export class Register extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        firstname: '',
        lastname:'',
        city:'',
        province:'',
    }

    this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this)
}
```

onSignup() function

```
onSignUp() {
    const { email, password, firstname, lastname, city, province } = this.state;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            firebase.firestore().collection("users")
                .doc(user.uid)
                .set({firstname,lastname,city,province,email})
            user.sendEmailVerification
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Data input (Only shows the Email one because they're all the same)

```
<View style={styles.textBoxView}>
     <TextInput
          style={styles.textBox}
          placeholder="E-mail"
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}/>
     <View style={styles.space}></View>
</View>
```

Oh, and the SignUp Button

```
<View style={styles.buttons}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onSignUp()}>
         <Text style={styles.textElement}>Sign up</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: Hey, I've posted an answer. If you feel that was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon so others will know this is resolved else feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try handling the 2nd promise which adds data to promise with `.then()`?

```
onSignUp() {
    const { email, password, firstname, lastname, city, province } = this.state;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            firebase.firestore().collection("users")
                .doc(user.uid)
                .set({firstname,lastname,city,province,email})
                .then(() => {
                    //user.sendEmailVerification
                })
                .catch(e => console.log(e))
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Also the `user.sendEmailVerification` looks incomplete. That returns a promise too and ideally should be handled:

```
user.sendEmailVerification().then(() => {
  console.log("Verification Email Sent")
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: Hi , so the part that said 
`firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid)             .set({firstname,lastname,city,province,email})`
is where the data is added to the firestore, as well as create the `users` collection.
So then what would I have to add in the `then` block?